# How to get IP and MAC addresses of the adapter that connects to the Internet?

Tags: c#, ip-address, mac-address

when using `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())`to get IP addresses and

```
    private System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress GetMacAddress()
    {
        foreach (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface nic in System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            // Only consider Ethernet network interfaces
            if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet &&
                nic.OperationalStatus == System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                return nic.GetPhysicalAddress();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

to get the MAC adddress, I get all addresses. Is there a way to get only the adapter and IP that actually connects to the net?

With above calls, I also get IP's and MAC's belonging to virtual adapters, such as the created by VMWare.

Regards
Jaime

Comment: You have to go through the ARP table and get the mac associated with the IP.  You can see table from cmd.exe >ARP -A

Comment: @jdweng I need to get the connected address using C#. Any idea?

Comment: How do you tell which one connects to the net?  It could be any of them except a loopback or localhost.  Just being a physical NIC doesn't give any assurance that the address can get out.

Comment: NIC is just looking at the ARP table.  A ping is a type of ARP message.  The PC automatically stores any ARP message that is one the subnet.  Every computer when turned on sends out an ARP so all other machine in the subnet know that a new IP enters the subnet.  Then sends out another ARP every 15 minutes.  If a machine doesn't see an ARP for 30 minutes it remove the IP from ARP table.   When a PING is requested the response from a PING is also save in table.  So the MAC address for the local machine you can look up the IP in the Dns.GetHostName() and then use to find MAC.

Comment: Why do you say not the localhost?  PC are configured differently and some machine have the loopback as localhost and some machines use the IP of the machine.

Comment: Finally I am getting the interface that has gateway address set. I am not completely sure if this is the correct approach but that way, only the connected interface was retrieved.

Comment: I think you mean the default gateway.  You can use from cmd.exe >IPConfig/all

Comment: By the way, I am doing all of this programmatically using C#, but you are right, I have realized about the gateway by issuing ipconfig command. I saw that among all the network interfaces, the only one that has gateway specified was the one that is connected to the network.

Comment: @jdweng Localhost (whether it's loopback or the machine's IP) would not be a path to the Internet.

Comment: @Duston: This is not a PATH/Connection issue.  The MAC is associated with the Ethernet Adapter and it doesn't need any connections.

Comment: @jstuardo: Connected is not the right term to use.  You would get the same results if removed the ethernet cable from machine.  It is really a PC configuration.

Comment: @jdweng OP's question says "..that connects to the Internet."  That's a path and not a physical connection.

Comment: @ Duston : The OP just meant Default Gateway which is not a connection.  It is a configuration.

Comment: @jdweng it really depends on the router configuration together with the PC configuration. If PC configures a static gateway, it will be considered also even if it is not connected to any network, but, it is not likely the case. Furthermore, remember the question. I need to get, programmatically, which interface is connected to the network (not necessarily to Internet) and at the moment, I have find out that by looking for the gateway is a good approach. All interfaces that are not connected to any network, have empty gateway configuration.

Comment: @Duston I have made a mistake in the question title. In the body I wrote "...that actually connects to the net.". I really needed to detect the interface that is connected to the network (independent if it is connected to Internet or not). If computer is a notebook which has WiFi and a cable connection, both will have gateway set, but in this case, I can choose any of them,

Comment: @jstuardo: Just want to continue discussion.  Your code cannot fix a configuration error in your network.  So if a router is not configured properly than your code will get bad results.  So yes it depends on the router, but you cannot fix a router issue.  So all you can do is find the default gateway on PC configuration.

Comment: @jdweng as I told, this is a good approach. I never told about trying to fix a configuration error, didn't I? Maybe the question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good approach, I am looking for the NIC that has a gateway set. This works in my case:

```
    private static IEnumerable<System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface> GetAllNetworkInterfaces(IEnumerable<System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType> excludeTypes)
    {
        var all = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(nic => nic.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Any() && nic.OperationalStatus == System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus.Up);
        var exclude = all.Where(i => excludeTypes.Contains(i.NetworkInterfaceType));
        return all.Except(exclude);
    }
```

And then, use it like this:

```
                var nic = GetAllNetworkInterfaces(new[] { System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel, System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback });
                txtRegistro.AppendText($"Local IP -> {string.Join(", ", nic.SelectMany(n => n.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses).Where(i => i.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).Select(i => i.Address.ToString()))}\r\n");
                txtRegistro.AppendText($"MAC Address -> {string.Join(", ", nic.Select(a => string.Join(":", a.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes().Select(b => b.ToString("X2")))))}\r\n\r\n");
```

With above code, I am getting which NIC has a connection to a network (LAN or WAN) as long as the connected router provides a gateway.

Regards

Jaime

Answer (score 0):

My adapter network interface have 5:

```
{"Id":"{FD94887A-FEEB-4F0B-AE11-D3A36137976B}","Name":"Ethernet","Description":"Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM","NetworkInterfaceType":6,"OperationalStatus":2,"Speed":-1,"IsReceiveOnly":false,"SupportsMulticast":true}
{"Id":"{765A365A-6D0B-4ACB-BCC8-779F481DC5D5}","Name":"Local Area Connection* 13","Description":"Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5","NetworkInterfaceType":71,"OperationalStatus":2,"Speed":-1,"IsReceiveOnly":false,"SupportsMulticast":true}
{"Id":"{D888C03B-82F1-4BBB-AB99-185F21B62159}","Name":"Local Area Connection* 14","Description":"Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #6","NetworkInterfaceType":71,"OperationalStatus":2,"Speed":-1,"IsReceiveOnly":false,"SupportsMulticast":true}
{"Id":"{56ECAAAF-8916-4358-A8DB-FB6E7448133D}","Name":"Wi-Fi 4","Description":"Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN","NetworkInterfaceType":71,"OperationalStatus":1,"Speed":135000000,"IsReceiveOnly":false,"SupportsMulticast":true}
{"Id":"{80377EDA-E86D-11E8-BA87-806E6F6E6963}","Name":"Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1","Description":"Software Loopback Interface 1","NetworkInterfaceType":24,"OperationalStatus":1,"Speed":1073741824,"IsReceiveOnly":false,"SupportsMulticast":true}
```

There are 3 attributes we need to care about: NetworkInterfaceType, OperationalStatus, Speed

This is my code:

```
private PhysicalAddress GetMacAddress()
{
    var allowNetworkInterfaceType = new[] { NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet , NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 , NetworkInterfaceType.GigabitEthernet };
    var networkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && allowNetworkInterfaceType.Contains(x.NetworkInterfaceType) && x.Speed > 0);
    return networkInterface?.GetPhysicalAddress();
}
```